# What is causing half of my Christmas tree lights to go out?

Tags: wiring, lighting

I have two strands of well used Christmas tree lights with incandescent bulbs. One is red and white, the other is multicolor. Both of these strands are only illuminating half of the bulbs in the strand.

The multicolor strand has no bulbs illuminated in the first half of the strand, closest to the outlet. The red and white strand has no bulbs illuminated in the second half of the strand, furthest from the outlet. Both strands have random individual bulbs that are out within the working section of bulbs.

[image]

I have confirmed with a multimeter that I can read 120VAC at the far end of both strands, so I know the entire strand has power. I can also power other strands from the far end of both strands with full brightness. So AC power is getting all the way through - both strands work normally as an extension cord.

I noticed that in both strands, the wiring appears to be different at the transition point between working and non-working bulbs. Nearly all of the strand has three individual conductors in the cable - EXCEPT at the transition point, between working and non-working bulbs.

The multicolor strand has three conductors for all of the non-working bulb section, and three conductors for all of the working bulb section. However, the wiring between the working and non-working sections has just two conductors. The red and white strand has the same arrangement, but the working and non-working sections are reversed, with the working bulbs closer to the outlet.

[image]
[image]

What is special about this small section of 2-conductor wiring? Why is this the point where the bulbs start/stop working, even when the entire strand is able to pass power to the far end? And, most importantly, how can I fix this so the entire strand lights up?

Comment: Did you know that in parallel with the bulbs there is a quite exotic "fuse" that short-circuits them when burning? That might help explain what's going on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess I'll just write it as an answer rather than a comment.

I think it is because you have a system with two strings of LEDs across the supply. Those two wires are the split between the strings where only power needs to be conveyed. So there's power on those two wires, just fine. Don't need to look there. You may have one or more bulbs out on the dark string.

Here's a simplified picture:

[image]

I've circled the 3-wire sections in green and the 2-wire intermediate stretch in red. That's why you see two sections in total, each with three wires between bulbs, these two then separated by a single segment with just two wires.

If one of the bulbs is out in one of the two strings, the entire string is out since they are in series. (It could also be a wire where the copper inside has been over-flexed too many times and finally failed. But that's unlikely here.)

Take each bulb, one at a time from the dark stretch and swap it with one of those in the working stretch. When the working stretch stops working, you've found a bad bulb.